# JQuery getting the second parent not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<li class="chatbox-item">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-header">
            <a href="#" class="close-chatbox">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

When `a.close-chatbox` is clicked, the `.item` element has to be hidden. However, I just can't seem to go up two levels to hide the `.item` element.

I have this JS:

```
$(".close-chatbox").click(function() {
    // not working
    $(this).parent().parent().hide(); 

    // not working, hides `.chatbox-item` element, and eq(1) doesn't do anything either
    //$(this).parents().eq(2).hide();
});
```

How can I get the `.item` element to be hidden when the `.close-chatbox` element is clicked?

Comment: Can you Reproduce this in `jsfiddle`

Comment: It looks like the error either can't be reproduced, or the code provided is insufficient to reproduce the issue here(https://jsfiddle.net/rukkwxgL/) is a jsfiddle with the exact code from the question copied into it demonstrating that the code works.

Answer (score 5):

Don't assign your action to a var, just use it:

```
$(function () {
    $(".close-chatbox").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/tkocx8ng/

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/tkocx8ng/2/ hide will hide it and then return the the hidden element, assigning it to a variable shouldn't stop it from working.

Comment: Hi, I had added the wrong piece of code to the question. I already had `$(this).parent().parent().hide();`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @erol_smsr Do you load jquery before ?

Comment: @erol_smsr Just updated my answer to add the event inside a JQuery document ready shorthand. Maybe it can fix your problem. But as you can see, in the Jsfiddle, it's works fine with the code you have posted. Do you have any error in the console ?

Comment: No errors in the console too, so weird and the updated answer doesn't work either

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the bug in a Jsfidlle ? Thanks you

Comment: @Magicprog.fr That's the problem, the same code works on JSFiddle, but on my system there's no error or anything. The exact same code just doesn't work here. And other JS code works perfectly. Mystery of life :O

Answer (score 4):

You can either use,

```
$(this).parent().parent().hide();
```

or you can use `.closest("element")`,

```
$(this).closest(".item")
```

Comment: He alerady tried `$(this).parent().parent().hide(); `

Comment: Using `.closest(".item")` would be my suggestion also.

Comment: @JqueryKing, but he was assigning it to a variable

Comment: @JqueryKing He don't, he just asign this to a var, so it's never executed in this case

Comment: @Magicprog.fr - "He don't, he just asign this to a var, so it's never executed in this case" it is the answer

Answer (score 2):

Use **.closest()** in jquery

```
$(this).closest('.item').hide();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ubur0qz5/1/)